# How can i have configure separate Site Title and Description field for different languages?

Tags: plone

For a multilingual site, I would like to define the Site Title and Description fields for each supported language separately for SEO purposes.

Is this possible with Plone or an addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Products.LinguaPlone; it is the defacto extension to use for multi-lingual sites.

To start with, you site will be configured with top-level, per-language root folders. Any visitor will be redirected to one of these folders (e.g. http://example.com/en/, http://example.com/fr/, etc.), providing you with per-language metadata including title and description.

Comment: but what about the site title & description defined in the Properties tab of the portal?